# Is there a simple way to write the query?

Tags: sql, sql-server

```
SELECT 
Col1+CASE WHEN EXISTS(SELECT 1 FROM Table2 T2 where T2.ID=Col1 AND T2.Initial='B') 
THEN '*' ELSE ''END ,
Col2+CASE WHEN EXISTS(SELECT 1 FROM Table2 T2 where T2.ID=Col2 AND T2.Initial='B') 
THEN '*' ELSE ''END ,
Col3+CASE WHEN EXISTS(SELECT 1 FROM Table2 T2 where T2.ID=Col3 AND T2.Initial='B') 
THEN '*' ELSE ''END 
FROM Table1
GROUP BY Col1, Col2,Col3
ORDER BY Col1,Col2,Col3
```

Is there a way to write the above query in more optimized method to get the same result?

Comment: What's wrong with it right now? Not readable? Too slow? Wrong answer?

Comment: Check my edits, that should be the same.

Comment: Looks like you have a history of not marking answers. (check the check mark) Please be sure to mark and up vote, it may sound silly, but that is why we help.

Comment: FWIW, you'd get an automatic 10 points if you accepted answers to all your questions. :)

Answer (score 1):

Yours should be the same as this, tho I'm not sure how much more optimized it might be.  Bit more readable perhaps:

```
SELECT 
    Col1+CASE WHEN T2.ID is not null THEN '*' ELSE ''END ,
    Col2+CASE WHEN T3.ID is not null THEN '*' ELSE ''END ,
    Col3+CASE WHEN T4.ID is not null THEN '*' ELSE ''END 
FROM 
    Table1 T1
    LEFT JOIN Table2 T2 on T2.ID=T1.Col1 AND T2.Initial='B'
    LEFT JOIN Table2 T3 on T3.ID=T1.Col2 AND T3.Initial='B'
    LEFT JOIN Table2 T4 on T4.ID=T1.Col3 AND T4.Initial='B'
GROUP BY T1.Col1,T1.Col2,T1.Col3
ORDER BY T1.Col1,T1.Col2,T1.Col3
```